# iOS iPad Application crashes after some time

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ipad

I have done an application which works fine for some time, and then just crashes instantly whenever launched. Here is the log (from Devices > View Device Logs) for the latest crash :
https://codeshare.io/KjJ8k

If I reinstall the application, it works just fine. But after a couple days or even more it crashes. Also multiple devices have been tested, same problem.

Comment: How did you installed the applications? If it's through XCode and you don't have a Paid Program Developper Account, the life expectancy of the app is like 24h, for a paid program, it's a few month with the correct certificate. With TestFlight, it's now 60 days.

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: @Larme I've installed through XCode, and I don't have a developer account. It's strange that it works for more than 24 hours; it may last more than that sometimes. Then the only solution is testflight or to buy a developer account?

Comment: @FilipLuch: There is no official time of validity for that. It may be 48h, but if indeed you didn't signed your app, it has low life expectancy. It's quite new that Apple allow it for free account, but it just for testing purpose (other than simulator), if you want more, you have to pay.

Comment: It's dying in splasboardd. Check if you have or had a splash screen and make sure you don't have something missing.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will buy an account and do it through crashlytics so that the app will remain for a longer time. @Larme please wrap it into an answer. Thank you